# How do I prevent Xcode from suggesting unavailable methods?

Tags: xcode

In Xcode 14.2 I frequently get autocomplete suggestions for unavailable methods. As an example, when I'm working on my current project with a minimum deployment target of iOS 14, I get the following suggestion:

[image]

In this menu, it's not clear that the minimum requirement of the suggested method is iOS 16. So I press enter, continue editing, and a few seconds later the compiler complains that this method is actually unavailable. This happens a lot, and it slows me down significantly, as I don't have all the Foundation stuff memorized.

What I would like to see when I type `URL(fil` is either a suggestion for `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` instead, or an immediate warning that `URL(filePath:)` is unavailable. Is there a setting for that?

Comment: Such methods are not actually unavailable. You would just need to wrap them in an `if #available(...)` check so they are only used with the correct version of the OS. It would be nice though if Xcode did show the relevant OS availability given your project's deployment target. That would help immensely. File an enhancement request with Apple.

Comment: These methods *are* unavailable in my project as I target iOS 14. The availablility checks don't help for this problem.